# JQuery - Element Selection

Tags: jquery

I'm relatively new to JQuery. I'm trying to understand how to select a child element. Currently, I have some HTML that is defined as follows:

```
<div id="elem1">
 <div class="display">Student 1</div>
</div>

<div id="elem2">
  <div class="display">Student 2</div>
</div>

<div id="elem3">
  <div class="display">Student 3</div>
</div>
```

When a user clicks a link, one of the elements (elem1, elem2, or elem3) is going to be passed to a function that is defined as follows:

```
function getNodeDisplay(node) {
  // NOTE: This does not work as desired
  return $(node).(#".display").html();
}
```

Unfortunately, this approach does not work. How do I get the HTML associated with an element that has a specific class or a given element? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about

```
function getNodeDisplay(node) {
  return $(node).find(".display").html();
}
```

the find function searches the dom tree under th current element.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the click event when the page is loaded, and pass the jQuery object straight to your method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div#elem*").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      getNodeDisplay($this);
    };
  };
});
```

div#elem* will match all div elements with the ID (#) beginning with elem.

To get the html:

```
function getNodeDisplay(node)
{
   return node.html();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(node).find(".display").html()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$("#elem1").click(function() {
   $(this).children(".display") //this is the child
});
```

[`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) gets immediate children, the alternative [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) finds *any* descendant. If you want to assign this click handler to all of those elements, just give them a class as well like this:

```
<div id="elem1" class="clickMe">
```

And change your selector to use it, like this:

```
$(".clickMe").click(function() {
   $(this).children(".display") //this is the child
});
```